# Brew cask uninstall does not remove installed cask

Tags: macos, terminal, uninstall, homebrew

I've installed cask via `brew cask install` and I would like to remove it, however, `brew cask uninstall` cannot find it:

```
me-bash-3.2:/$ brew cask list
macdown
me-bash-3.2:/$ brew cask uninstall macdown
Error: macdown is not installed
me-bash-3.2:/$
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
brew cask uninstall [appname] --force
```